# How to map my array variable in javascript to my model in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have javascript array variable created to store form input from user as below :

```
<script>
var networkdeviceItemsArr = [];
</script>
```

This array is use to load data into my Data Table. I already implement edit,delete and add function.

Example of my array data: [[1,John,19],[2,James,20]]

Below is the code I used to display data (test by key in data manually in db), this one work ok. I just dont know how to map the javascript array variable to my model, so I can save them to database.

```
@foreach (var childItem in items)
{
   if (childItem.Id != 0)
   {
     <tr>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.ItemsPaper[indexForItem].Items[indexForChildItem].Id)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.ItemsPaper[indexForItem].Items[indexForChildItem].Name)</td>
         <td>@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.ItemsPaper[indexForItem].Items[indexForChildItem].Age)</td>                                                 
         <td></td>
     </tr>                                            
    }    index++;
         indexForChildItem++;
    }
```

I already stuck for a week. Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a [nice post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) about it (10 years ago, omg).

Comment: You don't need to map it, just iterate througt the properties and assign them to your model  eg, myModel.Item =  arr[0].Item;

Comment: Sorry guys. I still didnt get it, i'm still new in doing development. Just two month.

Comment: @Alex, have you read that post? Which part of it you can't understand?

Comment: @vasily.sib yes. but does it mean i need to add new controller? I currently have a controller as this,     public ActionResult CheckList(Mymodel model) {//mycode}. Do I need to add another controller? Do I need to assign my binding to input using jquery to assign the javascript array variable?

Comment: @Alex, no. The whole post is about: 1. Make your HTML form inputs names like `items[0].Id`, `items[0].Name` and `items[0].Age`  2. Change your controller action to `public ActionResult CheckList(Mymodel[] items) { /* your code */ }`